# Lock data binding MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I've got a form with an Image component. I would like load image at runtime.
In my ViewModel, I've a property which represents the Path of the image source :

```
public string ImagePath { get; set; }
```

This property is binding to **Source** of my ImageComponent.
The problem is, when I start my application, ImagePath is null, and the default converter try to convert **ImagePath** to **System.Windows.Media.ImageSource** and raise an exception.

I've thought of 3 solutions :
 - Create a custom converter (which can give a default ImageSource when string is null)
 - Prevent view to get ImagePath (Don't know how)
 - Use a `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource` instead of string. (not sure the MVVM pattern is fulfill cause System.Windows.Media is only used by the view)

So my question is: Which solution is better (not only my 3) and what would be the implementation?

The XAML Binding :

```
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <Image Name="image" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Main.ImagePath, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
 </ScrollViewer>
```

The exception raised :

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '' from type 'String' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions;
```

Comment: Can you add the Control + Binding you are using in XAML?

Comment: Hmm weird I don't get that error no matter if I set the ImagePath to `null`, `""`, a valid or invalid path... maybe because I don't use the ViewModelLocator, I will also try that

Comment: Is it definitely `null`?  It looks like an empty `string` (`""`), which might explain why @Staeff can't reproduce.

Comment: both of them failed, I tried "" after null raised me an exception

Comment: what does the user of your application expects? maybe that could drive the solution.

Comment: The comportement is ok. I mean no image displays when the exception is thrown. The problem is just the exception

Comment: You don't need a custom converter to manage null values. You can do it in the binding of the source with `TargetNullValue`

Comment: I still don't get the error even when using Locator, but I will add my code as an answer anyways so you can see how it works for me. What .NET version and what VS version are you using btw?

Comment: I'm using VS2013, .NET 4.5 and MVVM Light ToolKit

Comment: @Guerudo Your solution works "TargetNullValue={x:Null}}". Could you please consider posting it as an answer ?

Comment: @Epitouille I'll do that immediatly

Comment: @Staeff Sorry for the time you spent :(

Comment: @Epitouille no problem, I'm just sorry for the asshole who downvoted me haha, but it still makes no sense to me why TargetNullValue works, because it only get's triggered when the value is already null and you just set it to null again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a previous comment, you don't need a custom converter to manage null values. You can use `TargetNullValue` in the binding of the source :

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <Image Name="image" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Main.ImagePath, TargetNullValue={x:Null}, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Moreover you could specified a default path in `TargetNullValue` if you wanted to.

Answer (score -1):

I've just started a vanilla MVVM Light project (.NET 4.5), and added the following stuff to my code and I don't get the error you are describing.

**MainViewModel:**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            return _imagePath;
        }
        set
        {
            _imagePath = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ImagePath);
        }
    }
    private string _imagePath;

    public RelayCommand ImageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _imageCommand ??
                (_imageCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ImagePath = "Image.png"));
        }
    }
    private RelayCommand _imageCommand ;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // I've tried both of those and it still works
        //ImagePath = "";
        //ImagePath = null;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow Content XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Image x:Name="TestImage"
               Source="{Binding Main.ImagePath,
                                Mode=OneWay,
                                Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
               Stretch="Uniform" />
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Button Command="{Binding Main.ImageCommand,
                              Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
            Content="Click" />
</StackPanel>
```